# Why is this returning a 0 when it should return a 10?

Tags: java, math

```
System.out.println((double)(20/200)*100);
```

I thought it was a rounding issue initially but the issue still persists when it's a double.

Comment: What do you think `20/200` will return?

Comment: Your cast into `double` is too late: it's already 0 by that time.

Answer (score 2):

This question is basically a duplicate, but since you seem to be on the right track, here is one slight change you can do to make this work:

```
System.out.println((20.0d/200)*100);
```

That is, make the ratio involve at least one `double` in the numerator or denominator.  After that point, you will have a `double` for the quotient, and multiplying by an integer will not change that precision.

Comment: The `0d` may be omitted, `20.` is enough for java to know that it's a `double`

Answer (score 2):

Because `20/200` is integer divison, hence it will truncate to 0 and the whole expression will return 0.

You should change to float division and to do that is enough to transofrm one of the operands to float type (ex: `20 / 200.0`).

Comment: It will floor it for positive numbers, *but* will ceil it for negative numbers. The better term is *truncate*, or *discard decimal places*

Comment: @Lino Right, changed.